# How to copy 1 (or a couple) files from parent folder into all subfolder

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a simple PHP way to copy 1 file (or a couple), say Image.jpg to all of the subfolders despite name. Can't seem to figure it out, would it be something like

```
<?php
$file = 'image.jpg';
$subdirs = '/*'; // I Actually need to go 2 subdirectories below

copy($file, $subdirs);

?>
```

Will this work?

I didn't see a PHP version in teh search results so that's why i ask

Comment: This may help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: Well that seems to just list files and directories. I'm trying to copy some.

Comment: `$subdirs` should be array of directories and you should use `foreach ($subdirs as $subdir)` and do copying in loop.

Comment: To answer your question `Will this work?` - No. You were pointed in the direction of `directoryIterator` - that will allow you to easily copy to all sub-directories if done correctly

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write some code to iterate over all sub directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `DirectoryIterator` class you could do something like this.

```
# permit auto-delete of any copied files, set false to disable.
$debug=true;

$depth=1;// limit recursion depth to this...

/*
    The target directory "textfiles" has 3 subfolders.
    Each subfolder initially had a single file - file.txt
    
    The files to copy are html files in a nearby directory
*/
$dir=sprintf('%s/textfiles/',__DIR__ );

$files=array(
    sprintf('%s/temp/page1.html', __DIR__ ),
    sprintf('%s/temp/page2.html', __DIR__ ),
);

/* utility to determine if the given dir is a dot/dbl dot */
function isDot( $dir=true ){
    return basename( $dir )=='.' or basename( $dir )=='..';
}


/*
    Iterate through the child folders and copy ALL files from given $files
    array into each subfolder. If the file already exists do nothing.
*/
$dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
$recItr=new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST );
$recItr->setMaxDepth( $depth );
    
foreach( $recItr as $obj => $info ) {

    if( $info->isDir() && !isDot( $info->getPathname() ) ){
        
        $path=realpath( $info->getPathname() );
        
        #copy each file
        foreach( $files as $file ){
            
            # determine what the full filepath would be - test if it already exists
            $target=sprintf('%s%s%s', $path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, basename( $file ));
            
            if( !file_exists( $target ) ){
                $status=copy( $file, $target );
                printf('<div>"%s" copied to "%s" - %s</div>',basename( $file ), $path, $status ? 'OK' : 'Failed' );
            }else{
                printf('<div>The file "%s" already exists in the folder "%s"</div>',basename( $file ),$path);
                
                # to test functionality, once file is copied 1st time it will be deleted 2nd time if debug is true
                if( $debug ) @unlink( $target );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need! Thank you Abronsius. I love the notes you provided as well. I did add an addition to it to overwrite the files if they already exist though, Good work!

Comment: I will ask, how do i make it so it's only one level deep into the subfolder? say if page1 and page 2 to is copied to "textfiles/folder1" as it should, I wouldn't want it to copy those files to "textfiles/folder1/images" for example.